# Android: Buttons Acting weird

Tags: java, android, button, textview

```
package com.example.artru_000.question;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class questioninterface extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final int QUESTIONS_LENGTH = 50;

    public void setQuestion() {
        for (Questions e : Questions.values()) {
            if (random(QUESTIONS_LENGTH) == e.order) {
                currentQuestion = e.question;
                correctAnswer = e.correctAnswer;
                answer1 = e.answer1;
                answer2 = e.answer2;
                clearWidgetsText();
                setWidgetsText();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void clearWidgetsText() {
        firstAnswer.setText("");
        secondAnswer.setText("");
        thirdAnswer.setText("");
        question.setText("");
    }

    public void setWidgetsText() {
        question.setText(currentQuestion);
        switch (random(2)) {
            case 0:
                firstAnswer.setText(correctAnswer);
                secondAnswer.setText(answer1);
                thirdAnswer.setText(answer2);
                break;
            case 1:
                thirdAnswer.setText(correctAnswer);
                secondAnswer.setText(answer1);
                firstAnswer.setText(answer2);
                break;
            case 2:
                secondAnswer.setText(correctAnswer);
                firstAnswer.setText(answer1);
                thirdAnswer.setText(answer2);
                break;
        }
    }

    Random rand = new Random();

    String currentQuestion, correctAnswer, answer1, answer2;

    public int random(int range) {
        return rand.nextInt(range);
    }

    Button getQuestion;
    Button firstAnswer;
    Button secondAnswer;
    Button thirdAnswer;
    TextView answerStatus;
    TextView question;

    public void setAnswerStatus(String status) {
        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Right")) {
            answerStatus.setText("Right");
            answerStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("wrong")) {
            answerStatus.setText("Wrong");
            answerStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
    public void buttonPushes() {
        getQuestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setQuestion();
                return;
            }
        });

        firstAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(firstAnswer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer)) {
                    setAnswerStatus("right");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                } else {
                    setAnswerStatus("wrong");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        secondAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(secondAnswer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer)) {
                    setAnswerStatus("right");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                } else {
                    setAnswerStatus("wrong");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        thirdAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(thirdAnswer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer)) {
                    setAnswerStatus("right");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                } else {
                    setAnswerStatus("wrong");
                    setQuestion();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void construct() {
        getQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_question);
        firstAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        secondAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        thirdAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answerStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongright);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questioninterface);
        construct();
        buttonPushes();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_questioninterface, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code above is like a trivia game. When you click the *getQuestion* button, you get a question and three buttons with 3 different answers. If you click the right button, it says it's right and gives you another questions. If you answer wrong, it says it's wrong and gives you another question. It works. The problem is, however, that sometimes i need to click the button several times in order to get the other question and the other answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding breakpoints to your code and running it in debug mode to pin-point where the weirdness is happening? Add breakpoints to your button clicks, where you decide what to do, where you output info and so on. If you have, tell us what you see.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? The buttons do work, but you have to click them more than once so the text is changed